# When do I need constructor in an Spring entity?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity

I am new in Spring and now working a Java project based on Spring Boot. When I was using Entity Framework, I have seen a similar usage that is used for lazy-loading. But I am not sure if it is true for Spring Framework. Could you pls clarify me why constructor is used for some of Entity classes in Spring?

```
public class Employee extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "employee_gen")
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;


    public Employee(
            @Nonnull String name
    ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return super.equals(other);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set value in the fields and don't want to do using a getter setter then simply you can pass the value as a constructer so that it will automatically initialize the object;

Otherwise, you have to do like this

**Without constructor**

```
Employee emp = new Employee ();
emp.setName("ex");
```

**With constructor**

```
Employee emp = new Employee ("ex");
```

Comment: Then if I do not need to use constructor, I should not define if in the entity, is that true?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: so does it mean getter and setter = constructor, but sometime i saw people using getter and setter and use constructor on SOME field only , why ?